# fromdate is ignored for /posts/{id}/comments requests

Tags: bug, status-completed, api, comments, api-v1

The api docs:
[http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help/method?method=posts/{id}/comments](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help/method?method=posts/%7Bid%7D/comments)

The [test request](http://api.superuser.com/1.0/posts/199943/comments?fromdate=1297487539).

You can see comment itself [here](https://superuser.com/questions/199943/reduce-time-machine-backup-sizes), it's four months old, while cutoff date in request is less than an hour ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, this is a pretty old one looks like.

Anyway, its been fixed.