# /comments?fromdate is broken?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

The following url should return 0 comments:

> http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/comments?fromdate=9999999999

Instead it returns all comments, not actually filtering by fromdate at all.

It happens on all sites as far as I know.

don't know if this is related:
[fromdate is ignored for /posts/{id}/comments requests](https://stackapps.com/questions/2004/fromdate-is-ignored-for-posts-id-comments-requests)

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed as of our most recent deploy.

Comment: total is still wrong, returns all instead of 0 etc

Comment: @Timmehmainframe - that too should be fixed now.